# Getting error on fetching using a simple PL/SQL Code on Apex-Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to use the PL/SQL command line and it keeps giving me Internal server error.

`

```
Declare

l_customer_name CUSTOMERS.NAME%TYPE;
l_credit_limit CUSTOMERS.CREDIT_LIMIT%TYPE;
cntr CUSTOMERS.ID%TYPE := 1;
max_id_customer CUSTOMERS.ID%TYPE;


Begin

    SELECT MAX(ID) INTO max_id_customer FROM customers;
    LOOP
        IF cntr > max_id_customer THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF;
        SELECT name, credit_limit INTO l_customer_name, l_credit_limit FROM customers WHERE ID=cntr;
            
        IF l_credit_limit > 70000 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cntr || ' : ' || l_customer_name || ' : ' || l_credit_limit);

        END IF;
    END LOOP;    
End;
```

`

The result keeps coming as `{ "code": "InternalServerError", "message": "Internal Server Error", "type": "tag:oracle.com,2020:error/InternalServerError", "instance": "tag:oracle.com,2020:ecid/005w1djNZUxFw0KimTtlWJ00025A0009bx" }`

I am simply trying to fetch data from the Database named customers and it is 100 records.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is "The PL/SQL command line" ? pl/sql is a procedural language, it has nothing to do with a command line. Since you tagged oracle-apex do you mean the "SQL Workshop" instead ?

Comment: Please provide table create script and some sample data (as script, not screenshot)

Answer (score 0):

I presume it is about endless loop; `cntr` starts with `1` and never increments.

For sample data:

```
SQL> select * from customers;

        ID NAME   CREDIT_LIMIT
---------- ------ ------------
         1 Little        10000
         2 Foot         513000
```

Fixed code (you're missing line #22):

```
SQL> Declare
  2    l_customer_name CUSTOMERS.NAME%TYPE;
  3    l_credit_limit  CUSTOMERS.CREDIT_LIMIT%TYPE;
  4    cntr            CUSTOMERS.ID%TYPE := 1;
  5    max_id_customer CUSTOMERS.ID%TYPE;
  6  Begin
  7      SELECT MAX(ID) INTO max_id_customer FROM customers;
  8
  9      LOOP
 10          IF cntr > max_id_customer THEN
 11             EXIT;
 12          END IF;
 13
 14          SELECT name, credit_limit
 15          INTO l_customer_name, l_credit_limit
 16          FROM customers
 17          WHERE ID = cntr;
 18
 19          IF l_credit_limit > 70000 THEN
 20             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cntr || ' : ' || l_customer_name || ' : ' || l_credit_limit);
 21          END IF;
 22          cntr := cntr + 1;        --> this
 23      END LOOP;
 24  End;
 25  /
2 : Foot : 513000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

On the other hand, you could do it simpler (if it has to be PL/SQL):

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select id, name, credit_limit
  3                  from customers
  4                  where credit_limit > 70000
  5                 )
  6    loop
  7      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.id ||' : '|| cur_r.name ||' : '||
  8                           cur_r.credit_limit);
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /
2 : Foot : 513000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

But, do you really need PL/SQL?

```
SQL> select id, name, credit_limit
  2  from customers
  3  where credit_Limit > 70000;

        ID NAME   CREDIT_LIMIT
---------- ------ ------------
         2 Foot         513000

SQL>
```